# Bash Columns SED and BASH Commands without AWK?

Tags: bash, sed, cut

I wrote 2 difference scripts but I am stuck at the same problem.

The problem is am making a table from a file (`$2`) that I get in args and `$1` is the numbers of columns. A little bit hard to explain but I am gonna show you input and output.
The problem is now that I don't know how I can save every column now in a difference var so i can build it in my HTML code later

```
#printf #TR##TD#$...#/TD##TD#$...#/TD##TD#$..#/TD##/TR##TD#$...
```

so input look like that :

```
Name\tSize\tType\tprobe
bla\t4711\tfile\t888888888
abcde\t4096\tdirectory\t5555
eeeee\t333333\tblock\t6666
aaaaaa\t111111\tpackage\t7777
sssss\t44444\tfile\t8888
bbbbb\t22222\tfolder\t9999
```

Code :

```
c=1
column=$1
file=$2

echo "$( < $file)"| while read Line ; do
Name=$(sed "s/\\\t/ /g" $file | cut -d' ' -f$c,-$column)
printf "$Name \n" 
#let c=c+1
#printf "<TR><TD>$Name</TD><TD>$Size</TD><TD>$Type</TD></TR>\n"
exit 0
done
```

**Output:**

```
Name Size Type probe
bla 4711 file 888888888
abcde 4096 directory 5555
eeeee 333333 block 6666
aaaaaa 111111 package 7777
sssss 44444 file 8888
bbbbb 22222 folder 9999
```

Comment: thx u for the fast answer !!! but the Challange is i may NOT using awk !! thats my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`:

```
celltype=th
while IFS=$'\t' read -a columns; do
   rowcontents=$( printf '<%s>%s</%s>' "$celltype" "${columns[@]}" "$celltype" )
   printf '<tr>%s</tr>\n' "$rowcontents"
   celltype=td
done < <( sed $'s/\\\\t/\t/g' "$2")
```

Some explanations:

1. `IFS=$'\t' read -a columns` reads a line from standard input, using only the tab character to separate fields, and putting each field into a separate element of the array `columns`. We change `IFS` so that other whitespace, which could occur in a field, is not treated as a field delimiter.
2. On the first line read from standard input, `<th>` elements will be output by the `printf` line. After resetting the value of `celltype` at the end of the loop body, all subsequent rows will consist of `<td>` elements.
3. When setting the value of `rowcontents`, take advantage of the fact that the first argument is repeated as many times as necessary to consume all the arguments.
4. Input is via process substitution from the `sed` command, which requires a crazy amount of quoting. First, the entire argument is quoted with `$'...'`, which tells `bash` to replace escaped characters. `bash` converts this to the literal string `s/\\t/^T/g`, where I am using `^T` to represent a literal ASCII 09 tab character. When `sed` sees this argument, it performs its own escape replacement, so the search text is a literal backslash followed by a literal t, to be replaced by a literal tab character.
5. The first argument, the column count, is unnecessary and is ignored.
6. Normally, you avoid making the `while` loop part of a pipeline because you set parameters in the loop that you want to use later. Here, all the variables are truly local to the while loop, so you could avoid the process substitution and use a pipeline if you wish:

   ```
   sed $'s/\\\\t/\t/g' "$2" | while IFS=$'\t' read -a columns; do
   ...
   done
   ```

Comment: the output is almost right, but there is a small problemu dont split them why ? look at my output up there :<tr><td>NametSizetTypetprobe</td></tr>
<tr><td>blat4711tfilet888888888</td></tr>
<tr><td>abcdet4096tdirectoryt5555</td></tr>
<tr><td>eeeeet333333tblockt6666</td></tr>
<tr><td>aaaaaat111111tpackaget7777</td></tr>
<tr><td>ssssst44444tfilet8888</td></tr>
<tr><td>bbbbbt22222tfoldert9999</td></tr>

Comment: Oh, those are literal backslashes and ts, not tabs? I can fix that.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer . how do u see where is your first column and second and third ... so i can use them as var? is my var(%s)? this should be later an HTML-Table...

Comment: The first column is `${columns[0]}`, the second is `${columns[1]}`, etc.

Comment: i think its still not so right... if u look at my SED u need 3 backSlash at the first (open and close puffer and then the Normal one with the t).. but i think its still don't separate them.. 
<tr><td>NametSizetTypetprobe</td></tr>
<tr><td>blat4711tfilet888888888</td></tr>
<tr><td>abcdet4096tdirectoryt5555</td></tr>
<tr><td>eeeeet333333tblockt6666</td></tr>
<tr><td>aaaaaat111111tpackaget7777</td></tr>
<tr><td>ssssst44444tfilet8888</td></tr>
<tr><td>bbbbbt22222tfoldert9999</td></tr>

Comment: it should look like something like that : 
<TH>Name</TH><TH>Size</TH><TH>Type</TH>
<TR><TD>bla</TD><TD>4711</TD><TD>file</TD></TR>

Answer (score 3):

This is tailor-made job for awk. See this script:

```
awk -F'\t' '{printf "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "<td>%s</td>", $i;print "</tr>"}' input

<tr><td>bla</td><td>4711</td><td>file</td><td>888888888</td></tr>
<tr><td>abcde</td><td>4096</td><td>directory</td><td>5555</td></tr>
<tr><td>eeeee</td><td>333333</td><td>block</td><td>6666</td></tr>
<tr><td>aaaaaa</td><td>111111</td><td>package</td><td>7777</td></tr>
<tr><td>sssss</td><td>44444</td><td>file</td><td>8888</td></tr>
<tr><td>bbbbb</td><td>22222</td><td>folder</td><td>9999</td></tr>
```